# create table like approach in PouchDB - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

newbie in Ionic and PouchDB. I saw this thread [PouchDB structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066753/pouchdb-structure) and I wonder if to make a collection or table-like in PouchDB, I should always add a column for something like "type"?

Because I wanted to do a simple todo list with User/Owner of that todo.

If I do this in SQL db, I would have table for users and table for tasks with user_id.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can go for per user per database approach to store to do list for each user.
you can create separate database for each user and store to-do list of that particular user in that database.

You can store each to-do task as separate document in database, we can consider it as a record or row in any SQL db.

per user database is best approach here rather then storing all user's to-do lists in single database.